# g++ Optimization Flags: -fuse-linker-plugin vs -fwhole-program

Tags: c++, linux, g++, x86-64, ld

I am reading:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

It first suggests:
In combination with `-flto` using this option (`-fwhole-program`) should not be used. Instead relying on a linker plugin should provide **safer and more precise information.**

And then, it suggests:
If the program does not require any symbols to be exported, it is possible to combine `-flto` and `-fwhole-program` to allow the interprocedural optimizers to use more aggressive assumptions which may lead to improved optimization opportunities. Use of `-fwhole-program` is not needed when linker plugin is active (see `-fuse-linker-plugin`).

Does it mean that in theory, using `-fuse-linker-plugin` with `-flto` always gets a better optimized executable than using `-fwhole-program` with `-flto`?

I tried to use `ld` to link with `-fuse-linker-plugin` and `-fwhole-program` separately, and the executables' sizes at least are different.

P.S. I am using gcc 4.6.2, and ld 2.21.53.0.1 on CentOS 6.

Comment: fwiw, following your quote - "Use of -fwhole-program is not needed when linker plugin is active (see -fuse-linker-plugin)." - we later see in the documentation - **"This option [`-fuse-linker-plugin`] is enabled by default when LTO support in GCC is enabled and GCC was configured for use with a linker supporting plugins (GNU ld 2.21 or newer or gold)."** - so i would guess that covers most reasonable modern installations of gcc. meaning they have a default option that makes `-fwhole-program` unnecessary. but this is just my interpretation of it all!

Comment: @underscore_d Great! Now, how do we turn the damned thing off?! (The fuse-linker-plugin, I mean.) Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582122/gcc-10-3-1-1-fc32-build-failing-with-gcc-fatal-error-fuse-linker-plugin-b

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE: See @PeterCordes comment below. Essentially, *-fuse-linker-plugin* is no longer necessary.

These differences are subtle. First, understand what *-flto* actually does. It essentially creates an output that can be optimized later (at "link-time").

What *-fwhole-program* does is assumes "**that the current compilation unit represents the whole program being compiled**" whether or not that is actually the case. Therefore, GCC will assume that it knows all of the places that call a particular function. As it says, it might use more aggressive inter-procedural optimizers. I'll explain that in a bit.

Lastly, what *-fuse-linker-plugin* does is actually perform the optimizations at link time that would normally be done as each compilation unit is performed. So, this one is designed to pair with *-flto* because *-flto* means save enough information to do optimizations later and *-fuse-linker-plugin* means actually do those optimizations.

So, where do they differ? Well, as GCC doc suggests, there is no advantage in principle of using *-fwhole-program* because that option assumes something that you then have to ensure is true. To break it, simply define a function in one .cpp file and use it in another. You will get a linker error.

Is there any advantage to *-fwhole-program*? Well, if you only have one compilation unit then you can use it, but honestly, it won't be any better. I was able to get different sized executables by using equivalent programs, but when checking the actual generated machine code, they were identical. In fact, the only differences that I saw were that line numbers with debugging information were different.

Comment: IIRC, linking with `gcc -O3 -march=native ... -flto` Just Works these days, and does all the necessary linker-plugin stuff.  (Pass the same optimization options to the link command as when you compiled.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you know if `gcc -O2 -march=native ... -flto` also does this? Many times, particularly for programs with the machine code on the hot paths larger than the trace cache, `O2` outperforms `O3` and `O3` is best applied to select functions. And, thanks for the update!

Comment: `-O2` also "just works" of course.  But only `-O3` enables auto-vectorization.  If any important loops can benefit from auto-vectorization it's usually worth the code-size cost.  Modern x86 CPUs don't use a trace cache, that was only Pentium 4.  The uop cache in Sandybridge / Ryzen isn't a *trace* cache; it doesn't follow jumps.  Plus, legacy-decode bandwidth is vastly better than in P4, so uop cache misses are not a disaster.  But yes, `O2` could be better overall for some large programs if L1i misses are a problem.

Comment: Note that modern GCC `-O3` does *not* enable `-funroll-loops`; that's only done for hot loops when you do PGO with `-fprofile-generate`  /` `-fprofile-use`.  Also, GCC 8 and later typically auto-vectorize with unaligned load/store instead of fully-unrolled prologue/epilogue to reach an alignment boundary.  That was always bad and super-bloated, spending most of the code-size for an auto-vectorized loop on the startup / cleanup, not unrolling the actual important part at all!  BTW, clang `-O2` *does* auto-vectorize, and unrolls small loops by default.