# What are use cases for GCC's `-fuse-linker-plugin`?

Tags: gcc, linker, link-time-optimization

I am trying to better understand link-time optimization in GCC and `-fuse-linker-plugin` seems to matter in that context. However, I do not exactly understand how.

Suppose my compilation with link-time optimization looks like this:

```
gcc a.c -c -o a.o -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects
gcc b.c -c -o b.o -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects
gcc main.c -o main.out a.o b.o
```

What would be a good use case for enabling `-fuse-linker-plugin`?

I found the official [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) somewhat confusing on that point. They suggest that `-fuse-linker-plugin` matters only for archive files (`.a`) but most conversation I have seen mentions that option without discussing archive files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606993/g-optimization-flags-fuse-linker-plugin-vs-fwhole-program

Comment: @KamilCuk That question is related but does not answer what `-fuse-linker-plugin` actually does. The GCC documentation suggests that this option only matters for archive files, but most conservation I have seen does not speak of archives at all.